# What to do when an equation returns nan as an answer?

Tags: c++, overflow, stack-overflow, nan, modulus

I've been having a slight issue with my program, what I'm trying to do is develop a way for users to simulate the possible strengths of passwords. This is assuming that all passwords are permutations (weird I know, but I presume that this is to stop data from becoming even more unwieldy.) using the equation...

//n!/(n-r)! when n! = (e^-n)*(n^n) sqrt(2(pi)n). When n is number of characters in use and r is length of password

No matter what I put I receive nan as an answer. I thought that perhaps my equation was off (maybe somehow I was dividing by zero) so I reworked it and simplified it a great deal. But that didn't seem to be the problem, though I feel that this got me closer to being correct. But I had the thought that maybe numeric overflow is having an effect here? But I really don't know how to fix something like that. I tried jumping from different data types but nothing seemed to work.

I have a problem with the modulus too. It returns back numbers less than zero for time, so with my noobish knowledge that tells me that maybe I'm overflowing it again but how else am I going to use % without defining it as an int? Maybe fixing the above problem will work out this one?

I would be beyond grateful for any help given to me. How does one go about dealing with return values of nan? Is there a step by step status quo for solving it? Is it pretty much always overflow or could it be something else?

The code itself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const int SECONDS_IN_YEAR = 31556926;
const int SECONDS_IN_DAY  = 86400;
const int SECONDS_IN_HOUR = 3600;
const int SECONDS_IN_MIN  = 60;

int main()
{

    int passwordLength ,characterSymbols;
    double instructionsPerSecond, instructionSuccess;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Equations needed
    // n!/(n-r)!
    //n is the number of letters in the alphabet
    //and r is the number of letters in the password

    // n! = (e^-n)*(n^n) sqrt(2(pi)n)
    double numeratorFactorial  = (pow(M_E,-characterSymbols))
                                *(pow(characterSymbols,characterSymbols))
                                *(sqrt(2*M_PI*characterSymbols));
    // (n-r)
    double characterMinusLength= (characterSymbols-passwordLength);

    // (n-r)! = (e^-(n-r)) * ((n-r)^(n-r)) * sqrt(2(pi)(n-r))
    double denominatorFactorial = ((pow(M_E, -(characterMinusLength)))*
                                (pow((characterMinusLength),(characterMinusLength)))
                                * (sqrt(2*M_PI*(characterMinusLength))));

    // n!/(n-r)!
    long double passwordPermutation = (numeratorFactorial / denominatorFactorial);

    // (passwords)* (instructions/Password) * (seconds/instruction) = sec
    int passwordSeconds = (passwordPermutation * instructionSuccess)
                         *(1/instructionsPerSecond);



    int passwordMin  = passwordSeconds / SECONDS_IN_MIN ;
    int passwordHour = passwordSeconds / SECONDS_IN_HOUR;
    int passwordDay  = passwordSeconds / SECONDS_IN_DAY ;
    int passwordYear = passwordSeconds / SECONDS_IN_YEAR;


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Explain purpose of program
    cout << "This program is designed to simulate the strength of passwords." << endl;

    //Ask for alphabet
    cout << "But first, share with me the max number of characters you'd be using."
         << endl;
    cin >> characterSymbols;
    //Reflect information
    cout << "We will be using " << characterSymbols << " character symbols to "
         << " construct the password.\n" << endl;



    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Input length of password
    cout << "\n\nWill you give me the length of proposed password?" << endl;
    cin >> passwordLength;

    //Repeat information
    cout << "The password length will be " << passwordLength << "." <<endl;



    //cout permutations
    cout << "This would lead to " << passwordPermutation << " unique password\n"
         << endl;



    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Ask for computer strength
    cout << "How powerful is this computer? How many instructions per second " << endl;
    cout << "can it accomplish?" << endl;
    cin >> instructionsPerSecond;

    //Read out computer strength
    cout << "The computer can do " << instructionsPerSecond << " instructions/second"
         << endl << endl;



    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Ask for instructions/password
    cout << "The number of instructions needed to test your password is." << endl
         << endl;
    cin >> instructionSuccess;

    //reflect
    cout << "This computer can do " << instructionSuccess
     << " instructions/password" << endl;


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    cout << "\n\nThe amount of seconds it'll take to crack this passcode is... "
         << endl << passwordSeconds << " seconds.\n\n\n\n\n" << endl;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Reflect all information in an easily readable table
    cout << "Number of character symbols using... " << characterSymbols      << endl;
    cout << "Length of password... "                << passwordLength        << endl;
    cout << "Number of permutations... "            << passwordPermutation   << endl;
    cout << "Instructions per second... "           << instructionsPerSecond << endl;
    cout << "Instructions per password..."          << instructionSuccess    << endl;

    cout << endl << endl << endl;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Add in conversions for min, hour, day, years
    cout << "Number of seconds to break..." << passwordSeconds << endl;


    cout << "Converted to minutes..."       << passwordMin     << endl;
    passwordMin = passwordSeconds / SECONDS_IN_MIN;
    passwordSeconds = passwordSeconds % SECONDS_IN_MIN;

    cout << "Converted to hours..."         << passwordHour    << endl;
    passwordHour = passwordSeconds / SECONDS_IN_HOUR;
    passwordSeconds = passwordSeconds % SECONDS_IN_MIN;

    cout << "Converted to days..."          << passwordDay     << endl;
    passwordDay = passwordSeconds / SECONDS_IN_DAY;
    passwordSeconds = passwordSeconds % SECONDS_IN_DAY;

    cout << "Converted to years..."         << passwordYear    << endl;
    passwordYear = passwordSeconds / SECONDS_IN_YEAR;
    passwordSeconds = passwordSeconds % SECONDS_IN_YEAR;

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: The community will be more likely to help if you are able to narrow down the problem to a much smaller amount of code. Try to reproduce the problem with as little code as possible.

Comment: An easier way to compute n! is tgamma(n + 1). You can also use lgamma to compute the log of the gamma function. But if r is small, you could just compute the number of permutations by just multiplying the numbers from n - r + 1 to n.

Answer (score 2):

"nan" stands for "not a number".  This is happening because you have declared the variables characterSymbols and passwordLength without giving them an initial value.

You must initialize any variable before you use it - if you don't then you will have undetermined behavior.  For example:

```
int x;
int y;
int z = x + y;
```

There is no way to predict what z will be equal to here because we don't know what x or y are equal to.  In the same way, your code should be something like:

```
int characterSymbols = 10;  //or whatever you want the initial value to be

...

double numeratorFactorial  = (pow(M_E,-characterSymbols))
                            *(pow(characterSymbols,characterSymbols))
                            *(sqrt(2*M_PI*characterSymbols));
```

In this way, numeratorFactorial will have a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you think you are declaring "equations" when you are actually declaring variables.  You write:

```
double numeratorFactorial  = (pow(M_E,-characterSymbols))
                            *(pow(characterSymbols,characterSymbols))
                            *(sqrt(2*M_PI*characterSymbols));
```

But `characterSymbols` isn't defined, only "declared".  `characterSymbols` is declared above it, but it doesn't have a value... yet.  Later on you use `cin` to get a value into it, but when you first declare `numeratorFactorial` you can't simply expect the program to insert the value into `numeratorFactorial` when `characterSymbols` changes.

Some definitions are probably in order:  The statement `double numeratorFactorial = some_value;` creates a variable named `numeratorFactorial` and uses `some_value` to fill that variable immediately.  What you want is a *function*, a logical statement that you can "pass values" to so values are generated when you need them.  For example, for your numerator factorial:

```
double numeratorFactorial(double characterSymbols) {
    return  (pow(M_E,-characterSymbols))
           *(pow(characterSymbols,characterSymbols))
           *(sqrt(2*M_PI*characterSymbols));
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Numerator Factorial test: " << numeratorFactorial(5.0) << std::endl;
}
```

Note that you cannot declare a function *within* the main function.

This sort of thing is programming fundamentals, and it seems like you are trying to run before you've learned to walk.  Get a good book like [C++ Primer](http://www.amazon.ca/Primer-5th-Edition-Stanley-Lippman/dp/0321714113) and pace yourself.